# Redirect URL to different IP address

Tags: url, ip, forwarding

I have 3 HTTPS IIS web servers at home all with different URLs configured. My WAN is a single dynamic IP address provided by my ISP.

I would like to somehow redirect to the correct web server and IP address based upon the `url` the client requests.

**Example**

```
domain.com:443 > 192.168.0.3
domain1.com:443 > 192.168.0.4
domain2.com:443 > 192.168.0.5
```

I have been reading up about reverse proxies and IIS ARR but all this seems to redirect to an application or directory within IIS on the same server.

Can anyone please recommend a simple way to just redirect a `url` to an IP address?

Something within Windows and not Linux based preferably.

Thank you for your help in advance.